# Why is it called Ayin Hara?

Tags: number, hebrew, words, ayin-hara-evil-eye

Why is it called Ayin Hara (singular) shouldn't it be Anayim Raos (Plural)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is way more simple that that offered in the other answer: The first person to give an Ayin Hara or attempt it was Billam. [He had only one functional eye.](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9952/showrashi/true#v3) Therefore we called it Ayin Hara.

Comment: Do you have a source for his being the first?

Answer (score 3):

The **Chida** in his Sefer **Pnei David** says since it is the way of people to close one eye it is called Ayin Hara he only uses one eye!!

Comment: What does that mean?